# Input mask with variable length sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to use an input mask on a text field... but I need it to allow variable lengths for each section of the mask.  For example:

The input mask could look something like this `"{{009}}m {{009}}yds"` where the 9 is a required number and the zeros are optional and would allow  the following results

```
"100m 500yds"
"1m 20yds"
```

There are a lot of mask plugins out there but I can't seem to find one that does this, they are all hard set lengths, i.e. you could enter "123m 123yds" but not "1m 3yds"

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

There is React component allowing masked input using sections of variable length:
[npm react-flexinput-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flexinput-mask)

[Demo page](https://orudnev.github.io/react-flexinputmask-demo/)